How to approach the RLS configuration for filtering multiple dimensions based on RLS applied on customer dimension?
I have a dataset having following columns:
Date, SaleAmt, Product, Customer, Client, ServiceProvider, Supplier.
The report will be shared with customers (external users).

The report model isn't yet designed
The report must have a slicer for following columns: Product, Customer, Client, ServiceProvider, Supplier
When Customer A opens the report, they should be only shown the Products, Clients, Suppliers, ServiceProviders associated with them. They shouldn't be allowed to see Products, Clients, Suppliers, ServiceProviders from other customers.

My solution is to have a calendar table, customer table, and the rest of the columns to be in one single main table. Thus, I can apply RLS on the customer table that will automatically filter the main table, and effectively all slicers will only show the data pertaining to that particular customer.
The side effect of this approach is that the table is no longer a star schema because everything other than date (calendar) and customer are in a single table.
In this situation what is the approach to design an ideal solution while making a star schema model?
